# Can we invoke a screen flow immediately when one screen flow is closed?

Tags: apex, help, flow-screen-component

I have a scenario where I need to open a VF page that displays the data from the Object which is updated in the Screen Flow. Until the transaction is completed in the first Screen Flow I can't display the updated values in the VF Page which will be opened from another Flow.
Is there a way to invoke the second screen flow as soon as the first screen flow transaction is completed?

Answer (score 0):

You can use "finishLocation" to start another process, call apex method or redirect to another vf/standard page.

```
<apex:page>
<flow:interview name="MyUniqueFlow" finishLocation="{!URLFOR('/home/home.jsp')}"/>
</apex:page>
```

Details are available here:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_flows_finishlocation.htm#pages_flows_finishlocation